# Model.create() throws errors with readonly attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have the following model in rails (simplified):

```
class Phone < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :brand
  attr_readonly :user, :brand
  attr_accessible :model, :phone_number

  validates :user, :presence => true
  validates :brand, :presence => true
  validates :model, :presence => true
  validates :phone_number, :presence => true
end
```

According to the documentation, attr_readonly should allow attributes to be set at creation, but not at update.

However, when I do this:

`Phone.create(:user => <existing_user>, :brand => <existing_brand>, :model => "Galaxy", :phone_number => "555-433-5678")`

I get this error:

`Can't mass-assign protected attributes user, brand`

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to assign a user and a brand association like that, you must define them as being accessible attributes:

```
attr_accessible :user, :brand
```

Otherwise, you can assign them like this:

```
Model.create({:user => user, :brand => brand }, :without_protection => true)
```

Comment: Ryan, it's a bit more complicated than that, since the model has two associations (I updated the example).  Even if I use the association builder for one of the `belongs_to` associations, I get the error for the other association.

Comment: Ryan - setting them as accessible defeats the purpose a bit.  I want the associations to be set at creation and then never altered; how would I achieve that if not via a attr_readonly setting?